# Powershell write-eventlog writes duplicate entries

Tags: powershell

I use PowerShell to parse some logs and write the result into a dedicated Windows Log. I meet the issue that `Write-EventLog` sometimes creates 2 times the same entry with a delay of 1 second.

I don't get why that happens. - Have you also meet this issue and how did you solve it?

Below my piece of code. - I added a `debug` which writes the content to a text-file. In the text-file there is only 1 time the content.

```
Function Publish-EventLog {

    param (                
        $logInfos
    )

    $eventlogs = @()
    Get-EventLog -List | Select-Object Log | ForEach-Object { $eventlogs += $_.Log }

    if ($eventlogs -contains('ABLogs')) {
        Write-Host "Log already exists." 
    } else {
        New-EventLog -LogName ABLogs -Source ABComputer
    }

    Write-EventLog -LogName ABLogs -Source ABComputer -EntryType $([string]$logInfos.WinEventType) -EventId $($logInfos.ABEventId) -Message $($logInfos.Details)   

    $runTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
    "Function, Publish: time : $($runTime)" | Out-File $logFile -Append
    "Function, Publish: logInfos.Details : $($logInfos.Details)" | Out-File $logFile -Append

} #End Function Publish-EventLog
```